# ¿Cómo lograr multi idioma en Unity pulsando en diferentes botones?

Tags: unity, idioma

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class Language : MonoBehaviour {

public int ingles = 1;

public string[] Texto_ingles;

public string[] Texto_español;

public Text[] Text;

public Button boton_español, boton_ingles;
// Update is called once per frame
/*void Update () {
    cambiarIdioma ();
}*/

void Start(){
    Button boton_español = gameObject.GetComponent<Button> ();
    Button boton_ingles = gameObject.GetComponent<Button> ();

}
void Update(){

//  boton_español.onClick.AddListener (IdiomaEspañol ());
//  boton_ingles.onClick.AddListener (IdiomaEspañol ());
    //
}

public void cambiarIdioma(){
    /*if (ingles == 0) IdiomaIngles ();
    if (ingles == 1) IdiomaEspañol ();*/

    if (boton_español.onClick.AddListener (IdiomaEspañol ())) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Idioma",IdiomaEspañol);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();

    }
    if (boton_ingles.onClick.AddListener (IdiomaIngles ())) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Idioma",IdiomaIngles);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();

    }


}

public void IdiomaIngles(){

    if (Text [0] != null) Text [0].text = Texto_ingles [0];
    if (Text [1] != null) Text [1].text = Texto_ingles [1];
}

public void IdiomaEspañol(){
    if (Text [0] != null) Text [0].text = Texto_español [0];
    if (Text [1] != null) Text [1].text = Texto_español [1];
}
```

}

Estaba intentando detectar idioma de serie del dispositivo pero incapaz, pero mediante botones tampoco,...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te puedo recomendar es utilizar archivos JSON para el manejo de multi-languages, ya que es mucho mas practico a la hora de cambiar estos.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

A la ves utilizar un diccionario para el manejo del texto, el cual solo cambia sus caracteres según el idioma que este seleccionado permitiendo cambiarlo en run-time.